# Using matrix theory to solve this problem

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, proof-verification

I'm sorry that I couldn't find a better title for this. I was wondering if my solution is valid for the following problem, or if I've made some mistake.

**Problem:** Let $N=\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ be a finite set with $n$ elements. Let $M_1, \dots, M_{n+1}$ be $n+1$ non-empty subsets of $N$. Show that one can always choose two non-empty index sets $I$ and $J$ in $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ such that $I \cap J=\emptyset$ and 
$$\cup_{i\in I} M_i = \cup_{j \in J} M_j.$$

**What I've done so far:** Consider, for every subset $M_l$, a vector $X_l$ such that $x_k=1$ if $a_k \in M$ and $0$ otherwise. All $X_l \not= 0$.

The problem statement is equivalent to saying that one can always choose two non-empty index sets $I$ and $J$ in $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ such that $I \cap J=\emptyset$ and $\{X_i : i\in I\}$ and $\{X_j : j\in J\}$ span the same space.

Assume the opposite is true, i.e. for every non-empty $I$ and $J$ the following holds: $\{X_i : i\in I\}$ and $\{X_j : j\in J\}$ span different spaces (or $I \cup J=\emptyset$, which will never happen since $I$ and $J$ are non-empty). This thus means that all $X_k$, $k=1,\dots,n+1$ are linearly independent, which leads to a contradiction since $n+1$ vectors of length $n$ cannot be linearly independent.

Comment: Your proof does not hold, if two sets of vectors of cardinality $k_1$ and $k_2$ span different spaces, it does not mean that their union span a space of $k_1 + k_2$. Moreover, you seem to assume that $I \cup J = \{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your proof does not work. That $\{X_i: i \in I\}$ and $\{X_j: j \in J\}$ span different spaces does not imply that $\{X_i: i \in I \} \cup \{X_j: j \in J\}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors.

For example: $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$ and $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$ span different spaces, but if you take all three vectors together, they are not linearly independent.

Take your vectors $X_k$. Since you have $n+1$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional space, there must exist scalars $\alpha_k$, with at least two of them non-zero, such that:
$$\sum_{k=1} \alpha_k X_k = 0.$$
Now, if $\alpha_k$ is negative, set $\beta_k = |\alpha_k|$ and put $k$ in the set $J$. If $\alpha_k$ is positive, put $k$ in the set $I$. If $\alpha_k$ is zero, do not put $k$ in any set. You can now write:
$$\sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i X_i = \sum_{j \in J} \beta_j X_j$$
and here the set of non-zero coordinates must be the same on both sides, implying the result:
$$\bigcup_{i \in I} M_i = \bigcup_{j \in J} M_j.$$

#### A stronger result

An interesting strengthening of this result is that if you have $n+2$ distinct $M_i$-sets, you can find disjoint non-empty $I,J$ such that 
$$\bigcap_{i \in I} M_i = \bigcap_{j \in J} M_j$$
**also** holds.

See Lindström, *Another theorem on families of sets*, Ars Combinatoria 35, 123-124 or Jukna, *Extremal Combinatorics*, Springer Verlag, section 14.2.